# Сворачивание кода в PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Можно ли в PyCharm как нибудь включить сохранение состояния свёрнутости определённых функций. Проблема - при перезапуске программы весь код разворачивается, что не очень удобно, до этого работал в Atom там такого не было.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm имеет настройку какие регионы будут свернуты по умолчанию `File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Folding`

Хотя я сейчас проверил у меня сохраняется состояние не зависимо от опций в этой настройке. Версия 2020.3.3 (Professional Edition)

Comment: Спасибо) после обновления у меня тоже по умолчанию стало так работать)